# bash: Putting a comment in commandline parameters

Tags: bash

I have a RHEL machine that I run many processes on. A lot of the processes may have equivalent start parameters, so from `top` and `ps` they are identical in this category and cannot be identified from one another.

How could I name or tag a process *in its parameters* so I can identify one from another? Aside from doing this in bash, how would I do this for a Java process or screen session?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is specific to java, you could pass an unused system property like so:

```
java -Dtag=process1  -jar ....
```

This not only shows up on the command line but is also visible inside the process, should you ever need that.

Answer (score 6):

The canonical way to do this would be to obtain the process id with `$!`. That way you don't tag the process, but you have an id that uniquely identifies it. For example:

```
gedit & gedit1=$!
```

This starts gedit and saves the process id in the variable `gedit1`. If I want to kill the process later. I can just write

```
kill $gedit1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a script like this

```
#! /bin/bash
"$@"
```

let's say you name it `process-label`. You can link different names

```
$ ln process-label other-label
```

and you can execute

```
$ process-label sleep 1800 &
$ other-label sleep 800 &
```

and you'll get your processes labeled

```
15016 ttys002    0:00.00 /bin/bash ./process-label sleep 1800
15017 ttys002    0:00.00 sleep 1800
15021 ttys002    0:00.00 /bin/bash ./other-label sleep 800
15022 ttys002    0:00.00 sleep 800
```

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think what you're looking for are aliases.
See here : http://www.stchman.com/alias.html .

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to do it with a parameter to the program but you could do this by hardlinking (or even symbolic linking) java to a different name and calling it through that.

For example:

In one terminal run the following:

```
$ cd /tmp
$ ln -s /bin/cat abc
$ ln -s /bin/cat def
$ ./abc
```

In another terminal run:

```
$ cd /tmp
$ ./def
```

In a third terminal run:

```
$ ps aux | egrep 'abc\|def'
```

You'll see one process with name 'abc' and one with name 'def' and neither has the name 'cat'.  So if you do this, creating a different link for each of the processes, then you can differentiate them.

Comment: Isn't that just an alias that wouldn't help me identify one process from the other?

Comment: @hexacyanide it does help.  When my edit is approved, see the example I added to this answer.